# What kind of functions can be represented as infinite linear combinations of exponential functions?

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function defined in $(0, \infty)$. I am curious what kind of $f(x)$ has the following representations:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j e^{-jx}, \quad \forall x \in (0, \infty).
$$

My initial thought was that consider the transformation $s = e^{-x}, s \in (0, 1)$, then we want to find $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ such that
$$
f(-\log s) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j s^j, \quad \forall s \in (0, 1)
$$

That means we may consider the Taylor expansion for $f(-\log s)$ at $s=0$, but then $-\log s = \infty$, for which the Taylor series is not well defined (at infinity).

So is there a method to determine $a_j$ if $f(x)$ can be represented as an exponential sum?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, thanks for the answer, now I am clear about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}$You were almost there.

Indeed, suppose that
$$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j e^{-jx}\in\R \quad \forall x\in(0,\infty). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Then
$$g_f(s):=f(-\ln s)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j s^j\in\R \quad \forall s\in(0,1).$$
So, the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j$ is $1$. So, $g_f$ can be extended to the analytic function $G_f$ on the open unit disc
$D$ in $\C$ given by the formula $G_f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j$ for $z\in D$.

Vice versa, if the function $g_f$ can be extended to an analytic function $G_f$ on
$D$, then $G_f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j$ with $a_j=G_f^{(j)}(0)/j!$ and hence \eqref{1} holds.

Thus, \eqref{1} holds for some $a_j$'s if and only if the function $g_f$ can be extended to an analytic function on $D$.

Similarly, \eqref{1} holds for some $a_j$'s if and only if the function $g_f$ can be extended to a real-analytic function on the interval $(-1,1)$.

---

For an illustration, suppose that $f(x)=\dfrac1{1-e^{-x}}$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$. Then $g_f(s)=f(-\ln s)=\dfrac1{1-s}$ for $s\in(0,1)$. Clearly, the function $g_f$ can be extended to the analytic function $G_f$ on $D$ given by the formula
$$G_f(z):=\dfrac1{1-z}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j$$
with $a_j=G_f^{(j)}(0)/j!=1$. So,
$$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j e^{-jx}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{-jx}$$
for $x\in(0,\infty)$.